# How pexpect analyzes stdout of the child?

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

There is the following code:

```
child = pexpect.spawn("prog")
#some delay...
child.expect(Name .*: )
child.sendline('anonymous')
```

When the child process has been launched it can start to send to its stdout a lot of data e.g. log info. Does it mean pexpect start to look up through all child's stdout (from the start of process to the current moment)? Or pexpect starts to do it after `expect` calling only?

My child process makes a lot of log info. And CPU's going very slow. I suppose such pexpect's implementation can be cause

Comment: What's *analize*? And what's *CP*?

Comment: @whjm i.e. does pexpect store all stdout data? when `child.expect()` is calling  does pexpect look up through all stream (from start of process to the current moment)? if this true then pexpect  performs a lot of work (if the child writes many data for its stdout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a child process is spawned, the child will `write()` its data to the pty (slave side) and waiting for the parent to `read()` the data from the pty (master side). If there's no `child.expect()` the child's `write()` may be blocked when it's outputing too much data because the write buffer is full.

When `child.expect()` matches a pattern it'll return and then you have to call `child.expect()` again otherwise the child may still be blocked after it outputs too much data.

See following example:

```
# python
>>> import pexpect
>>> ch = pexpect.spawn('find /')
>>> ch
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7f47390bae90>
>>>
```

At this time the `find` is spawned and it's already outputted some data. But I did not call `ch.expect()` so the `find` is now being blocked (sleeping) and it does not consume CPU.

```
# ps -C find u
USER     PID %CPU %MEM  VSZ   RSS TTY     STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root  100831  0.0  0.2 9188  2348 pts/12  Ss+  10:23   0:00 /usr/bin/find /
# strace -p 100831
Process 100831 attached
write(1, "\n", 1             <-- The write() is being blocked
```

Here the STAT `S` means *sleeping* (and `s` means *session leader*, `+` means *foreground process*).

---

According to pexpect's document, two options of spawn() may affect performance:

> The `maxread` attribute sets the read buffer size. This is maximum number of bytes that Pexpect will try to
>   read from a TTY at one time. Setting the `maxread` size to `1` will turn off buffering. **Setting the `maxread`
>   value higher may help performance in cases where large amounts of output are read back from the child.**
>   This feature is useful in conjunction with `searchwindowsize`.
>
> When the keyword argument `searchwindowsize` is `None` (default), the full buffer is searched at each iteration of receiving incoming data. The default number of bytes scanned at each iteration is very large
>   and **may be reduced to collaterally reduce search cost**. After `expect()` returns, the full buffer attribute
>   remains up to size `maxread` irrespective of `searchwindowsize` value.